# Rigid Body Sphere Shows In Rendered View But Not In Rendered Image and Animation

Tags: physics, rigidbody

I have created a roulette wheel trying to get the physics engine to work with it and I have a rigid body for all and they collide when in the rendered 3D view but rendering the image or animation it does not show up. Ill take some screenshots for a better understanding.
[image]

Here is the sold view and it is showing up in the scene.
[image]
Now I switch to rendered view and all the textures with the sphere still in the scene and works when the animation is played.
[image]
Then rendering the image the sphere disappears and I assume it had to with the physics or something but not totally sure and has screwed up my animation.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting! Can you post the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yes here is the file. I've only used blender for about a month so the model is very basic. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4827" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4827/)

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your error. If I render your setup as is, I get a blank render. So I unchecked sequencer in Post Processing, and the result is an image that includes the sphere. This is probably not what you're looking for though?

Comment: I am not totally sure it might be from my project being baked I will try moving the project into a new save file and see if that works and Ill get back you as I think that may be the case.

Comment: So I tried turning of sequencer and got the same thing as you said. It was what I was looking for but do you have any idea on why the sphere wouldn't show up? Or atleast be able to explain what turning off sequencer did?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but this is my guess. I poked around and saw you have something on your video sequence editor (VSE), and sequencer enables the editor. I'm assuming the image you had on your VSE was your image with no sphere, and that's why it was showing up blank on my end. So what happened when you had sequencer checked is that the image with no sphere on your VSE gets priority.

Comment: Alright thanks so much for the help moarorleslie I really appreciate it!